# Interpreting the Contravariant derivative being zero

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm doing some calculations for Riemannian manifolds and I'm having trouble understanding one of the results.

Under certain conditions, I've shown that for an antisymmetric rank two tensor $F_{ij}$, the following is true:
 $$g^{jk} \, \nabla_k F_{ij} = \nabla^j F_{ij} = 0$$
I'm not sure how to interpret this however, either geometrically or physically. 
(As you probably suspect, $F_{ij} = \partial_i A_j - \partial_j A_i$, and we are using the Levi-Cevita connection.)

Comment: If you use differential form notations, then $F = dA$ and $d^* F = d^*dA = 0$. Not sure if that is helpful....

Comment: So you think this is some curved-space analogue of Maxwell's equations?

Comment: For the maxwell's equation, it would be sth like $dF = 0 = d^*F$  for no external fields. So it is not really the same thing.